# What hosting do people normally use to publish Django web-site?

Tags: django, hosting

I have small Django web-site, which I've wrote in learning purpose, but now I'd like to publish it in Internet.
Dear Stackoverflowers, could you please recommend any *free* Django providers which are convenient to work with?

Sorry, if that is a stupid question.

P.S. I've searched in the Internet, and found some providers, but I can't decide which is good. Need your advice.

Comment: Welcome, but that's not what this site is for.

Comment: Hi. Please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before asking questions.

Comment: Sorry. I've read the FAQ and thought that my question is ok. But I'm new here.

Comment: *" I've searched in the Internet, and found some providers, but I can't decide which is good."* Please summarise your research, and why you cannot decide between these choices.

Comment: I've found a list of Django providers at (http://freedjangohosting.com). There are a lot there. Also I've been told about [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com) and they offer free account (limited). But to decide I'd really like to know pro's and con's from people that have experience.

Comment: That's the thing, though, you explicitly asking for subjective responses. When you vote to close a question to further responses, one of the choices (that gets used a lot) is ***Not Constructive**: As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q & A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.* The chat rooms are appropriate to this type of discussion.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here, as I've already mentioned, so I don't precisely know what kind of questions are good and which are don't. But I've seen hand full of highly discussed topics with the same style as mine. For example about [IDEs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126753/is-there-a-good-free-python-ide-for-windows) or [web-frameworks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202939/which-python-framework-to-use). And they are actually very helpful for newbies. I intended to ask a question in the same way.

Comment: shameless plug for our own service, [PythonAnywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com), which offers free hosting, and we try to make it super-easy for beginners...

Answer (score 8):

Free cloud hosting service for django applications with postgres available on Heroku. I deployed an app in like 20 mins.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django

Comment: Also deployed using `Heroku`.  You can skip the part about `virtualenv` if you are using an IDE to develop.  Also, I skipped the `PostgreSQL` stuff since I am using `MySQL (clearDB addon)`.

Comment: Heroku is a real pain to get working with everything. It needs a fairly specific folder structure. Static files are a pain.

Answer (score 3):

I believe [Heliohost](http://www.heliohost.org/home/features/languages/python) is popular and comes highly recommended. I've not used it myself, but it is probably worth checking it out.